# There is a blank space below navigation

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

There is a blank space below navigation.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

It seems that my view has been pushed down by the blank space.and i have been set myChatView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false,but it desn't work.

Comment: Add this line self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; in your viewWillAppear and check once...

Answer (score 1):

Unselect the autoscrollview through storyboard.

[image]

(or)

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

unselect the adjustscrollview insect for your view controller :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro any mistake i did ?

Comment: I've done it like you said,but it not working,I was using Teodor Patras's SideMenuController on github before I had this kind of situation.@KishoreKumar